# How to convert ionic1 to ionic2 code

Tags: ionic-framework

i want to convert my ionic App from ionic1 to ionic2 because some of the things are not working in ionic1. so could any one tell me to how to do this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic 1 and Ionic 2 are different, because of angular, angular 2+ it's a complete re-write of angularjs. The best way to do this will be by starting to learn the new angular. However this shouldn't be hard to learn. I started by taking a look to new angular doc [here](https://angular.io/docs), reading this [upgrade](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) guide and also Ionic doc [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/).